# Elastic search pattern match not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, pattern-matching, elasticsearch-query

I am trying to pattern match the msg `Cannot allocate memory`.
I was hoping it will print only if it matches entire msg only but it is printing even it just matches a word 'Cannot or allocate or memory' in the documents.

Can you please suggest if any modifications are needed for this query?

Query:

```
GET /_search?pretty
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "Cannot allocate memory"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "timestamp": {
            "gt": "now-1h"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "took":186,
  "timed_out":false,
  "_shards":{
    "total":2337,
    "successful":2337,
    "skipped":2331,
    "failed":0
  },
  "hits":{
    "total":10,
    "max_score":38.4559,
    "hits":[
      {
        "_index":"MMJ-2020-06-08-18-45",
        "_type":"_MMJ",
        "_id":"49605400288259767318470290294414874485955515962252853330.0",
        "_score":38.4559,
        "_source":{
          "message":"Cannot allocate memory",
          "host":"MMJ",
          "processed":"2020-06-08T19:10:22.046111Z",
          "stack":"",
          "timestamp":"2020-06-08T19:10:21.927881+00:00"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index":"MMJ-2020-06-08-18-45",
        "_type":"_MMJ",
        "_id":"49605400288215165828073229047621636353532845727514886194.0",
        "_score":11.734165,
        "_source":{
          "message":"found character %'%' that cannot start any token",
          "host":"MMJ",
          "processed":"2020-06-08T19:10:21.938001Z",
          "stack":"",
          "timestamp":"2020-06-08T19:10:21.926992+00:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `default_operator` -- it defaults to `OR` but you need an `AND`:

```
{
  ...
  "query_string":{
    "query":"Cannot allocate memory",
    "default_operator":"AND"
  }
  ...
}
```